# Visibility off iphone application on China appstore

Tags: ios, app-store

I have app translated for en, ru and es. Today I have started to working on chinese translate. My friend from china tried to find my app on china appstore but he can't. My app I set to all appstores. What can be wrong? Is there any reasons?

Comment: What is the name of your app?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps for viewing the app in China AppStore in WebBroser.

1. Search in iTunes the App (available in any AppStore)
2. Then copy the link and open it in WebBroser.
3. Then change the country code to desired country code you wish to view the app.

   Example:

   https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/china-daily-news-for-iphone/id330543698?mt=8 (US AppStore)

   https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/china-daily-news-for-iphone/id330543698?mt=8 (China AppStore)